# Flink - how to trigger refresh on source

Tags: apache-flink

My program has two streams - one data stream and another enrichment stream. The enrichment stream is broadcasted and connected to data stream. The enrichment stream refreshes occasionally, but sometimes is stale for data stream data. My requirement would be to refresh the enrichment stream when this condition occurs.

Any recommendations on how that can be achieved?

Comment: When you say "...sometimes is stale for data stream data", are you saying that the enrichment stream doesn't refresh as expected, or that you get records in the data stream that have been enriched with older (stale) enrichment data, even when newer enrichment data has been loaded?

Comment: The enrichment stream can be loosely be thought of as a cache -- it still hasn't updated because of whatever reason but data stream has recvd data for which enrichment was not found (cache miss). The enrichment stream that I am working is also not event driven but more like http query.

Comment: When enriching the data stream, is it a keyed join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular use case, assuming enrichment is based on a common key value between the data and enrichment streams, and you can use an HTTP pull (vs. push) model, then I would recommend the following:

1. Partition your data stream using the key value.
2. Run this partitioned data stream into an Async IO function, where you first check a cache, then make the HTTP request to get the appropriate enrichment data.
3. Save the enrichment data in a local cache (e.g. using Guava), where you can control the cache size and TTL.

The cache data will be lost on a restart, but normally that's OK. Note that the cache will need to be thread-safe, as the completion of the async HTTP request will be multi-threaded.